# Click the list item to show the contents in separate activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

While clicking the `Map1` list item, I need to show the `Category1.java` Class contents in separate activity.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.steph.listview;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 String[] parentArray = {"Map1","Map2","Map3","Map4","Map5"}; 

 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,parentArray);

 setListAdapter(adapter);

 ListView lv = getListView();

 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
 long id) {


 }
 });
 }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
   </LinearLayout>
```

**Output:**

Finally, I got an output like this.

[image]

Now my only problem is if I click the `Map1` list item, I need to display the contents in separate Activity.So that I am creating the `Category1` class for that. Below I am posted the codes related to `Category1`.

**Category1.java:**

```
package com.steph.listview;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Category1 extends Activity {

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.category1);
}

}
```

**category1.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Map contenets have to display in this textView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But `Map1`  is not an Activity...

Comment: In Category1.java class why you are extending Fragment if you want to display content in separate activity?

Comment: It should either extends "FragmentActivity" or "Activity"

Comment: @Kat-hat I got confused in that.I am edited the post

Comment: @Naruto  Now what's your problem?

Comment: @Manish If I click the Map1 in list item,I need to show the TextView and button contents placed in Category1.java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.steph.listview;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity 
 {

  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final String[] parentArray = {"Map1","Map2","Map3","Map4","Map5"}; 

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,parentArray);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Map1.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", parentArray[position]);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
}
```

**Map1.java:**

```
   package com.steph.listview;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.widget.TextView;

     public class Map1 extends Activity 
       {
         TextView textView;
         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
          {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.category1);
           textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
           textView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("id"));
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like to do that, you can use following code

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Category1.class);
    i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Then in the `Category1` Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MainActivity.java:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                if(position==0){
                    Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Category1.class);
                    intent.putExtra("TagName", data);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            }
        });
```

Category1.java:

Inside `oncreate()`

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("TagName");//If data is of string type
```

Comment: Thank you.in your answer you set a position that will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your onItemClick call

```
StartActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Category.class).putExtra("data",parentArray[position]));
```

then in OnCreate of your Category1

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("data");
```

Then Set the data on your Textview

```
TextView myText =(TextView)findviewbyid(R.id.textView1);
myText.setText(data);
```